# Angular2 Plugin Install in Eclipse

Tags: angular, eclipse-plugin

Getting the following error while installing Angular2 Plugin in Eclipse:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://oss.opensagres.fr/angular2-eclipse/1.1.0/plugins/ts.eclipse.ide.server.nodejs.embed.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.0.201611012122.jar.
Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 5614836; received: 3459582
Unable to read repository at http://oss.opensagres.fr/angular2-eclipse/1.1.0/plugins/ts.repository_1.1.0.201611012122.jar.
Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 3698906; received: 565502

Can anyone help?